# Search on multiple tables with different columns

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I want to build a search engine for my website. My database table list is as follows:

1. `d_name`: I need to search on **two** columns.
2. `em`: I need to search on **one** column.
3. `seri`: I need to search on **one** column.
4. `topics`: I need to search on **one** column.
5. A lot of other tables which the number of them is dynamic and the list is included in a column in `d_name` table. I need to search on **two** columns on each of these tables.

As the number of results may be large, I need to make a pagination as well.
As I know, I should use `UNION` in order to use the pagination on search on multiple tables but first, the number of columns  should be the same but here isn't and also the number of my tables is dynamic.

On the other hand, if I try to use `SHOW TABLES` it will also search some other tables which my private information is included in them.

This is what I've so far done:

```
        $query = "(SELECT d_name, doc, db_name AS d FROM d_name WHERE d_name LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%') 
           UNION
           (SELECT em_name, db_name AS em FROM em WHERE em_name LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%') 
           UNION
           (SELECT name AS topic FROM topics WHERE name LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%')
           UNION
           (SELECT seri_name, db_name AS seri FROM seri WHERE seri_name LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%')";
```

But the `UNION` doesn't work! Does anybody know what should I do?

Comment: did you even try to do something on the same? Please start trying first

Comment: atleast show what have you done so far. Stackoverflow is there to help when you have a problem in doing something.

Comment: Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you perform an UNION-query all seperate queries should have the same number of columns in the result. You can use fixed values like `NULL`, `''` or `'not provided'` to fill up the other tables.

Examlpe-query ([demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/188bb/1/0))

```
SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM i_have_two_columns
UNION
SELECT column_1, NULL FROM i_have_only_one_column
```